# JPA batch insert doesn't free up memory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to use SpringBoot JPA to insert like 100k items (entities) into database. But JVM runs out of memory.

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(this.folderPath))) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(Parser::parse).forEach(item -> {
                log.debug("Load trade : " + item.getId());
                itemService.save(item);
            });
        }
```

where itemService is a service that use ItemRepository and ItemRepository is a JPA repository:

```
ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, String> {}
```

In applicateion.yml, I have put the following settings and hope this will avoid memory leak:

```
jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        generate_statistics: true
        jdbc.batch_size: 2000
```

My understanding is that this will perform batch inserts for every 2000 instances and free up memory after each batch insertion. However, I still got run out of memory exception. To me, it looks like itemService holds up all the trades so no GC is performed.

I am a newbie to JPA and could someone please point out to me what I could do in order to avoid memory leak?

Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `saveAll` method in order for batch update to work.

E.g

```java
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(this.folderPath))) {
    List<Path> files = paths
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (List<Path> batch : Lists.partition(files, 2000)) { // Lists from Guava, batch will be 2000 elements or less.
        List<Item> parsed = batch.stream().map(Parser::parse).collect(Collectors.toList());
        itemService.saveAll(parsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the main issue is Memory leak. In your above case, you have to save all the instance in memory (List), which will still cause memory leak in my case.

Comment: @GuifanLi yep, overlooked it. With the help of `Lists.partition` method from guava library you can save them in portions. Adjusted the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work your batch, it is missing this additional configuration to rewrite batched inserts way:

```
 jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourDB?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
```